# Representing a single element of a join table in a hibernate entity by version date

Tags: java, hibernate, join, version

I have a Hibernate Entity representing our `Partner`s. We want to associate that partner to an active '`Type`' (another entity) through a join table (Since `Type` can be used in many scenarios). The caveat is that the join is date based (versioning).

What I want is something like:

```
Partner.getActiveType()
```

represents

```sql
select * from partner_to_type_map 
where partner_id = xxx 
and now() between effective_from and effective_to;
```

I could of course represent the join table as an entity and them have that entity referencable in my `Set<PartToTypeMap>` but that would make using it terrible clunky. I would have to marshal that data them sort through it to find the right one. I can do this with a dao and some HQL but I would love for the correct object to just BE there.

join table is:

I looked at the `@Version` annotation but it doesn't seem to be what I want (though I could be wrong).

I can post code if needed but really, `Partner` is a simple entity.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `partner_to_type_reg_map` (
  `partner_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `account_key_type_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `effective_from` Timestamp NOT NULL,
  `effective_to` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`partner_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_key_type_id` (`account_key_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at @Where & @WhereJoinTable association - this will allow you to add a condition to the association mapping. More details in [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection)